# css :not pseudo not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a set of buttons on a wysiwyg textarea that I do not want to apply a .btn class to. I am using Bootstrap 3 and using the :not pseudo selector but the .btn is not getting applied to anything once I add the :not

```
.btn:not(.wysihtml5-toolbar .btn) {
    padding: 10px 27px 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: .3s;    
}
```

Comment: Yes I had that originally then I read an example here that had a space. http://codepen.io/grayghostvisuals/pen/lnkuL

Comment: I think I have the answer. :not does not seem to work when applied to a class. It only seems to work for html tags like you have and the example I was looking at has. So for div:not, span:not works but .btn:not does not

Comment: I remove my comments... because Im little confused now... I dont now maybe its to late now for me... but you can use classes... AND **you can use spaces** between the :not() selector... you can read more here with example-> [:not() -CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and I make an fiddle so you can try out...[Try out](http://jsbin.com/hiniquxe/1/edit)